# jade cli environment variable in --obj

Tags: bash, shell, pug, command-line-interface

I want to be able to use an environment variable in the --obj of the `jade` cli so I can do this:

```
$ jade some.jade -O '{"version": "${VERSION}"}'
```

Where `VERSION` is an environment variable. But right now `"${VERSION}"` is what I see in the output. Is there a way to accomplish this? I've tried all kinds of variations on escaping.

Comment: Did you try `$ VERSION=text jade some.jade`  and then read with `process.env.VERSION`?

Comment: Boom! That totally worked! Thanks!

Comment: Any way I can include that environment variable in my `--out` option? Something like: `jade other/index.jade --out dist/$VERSION/`

Comment: If you mean `$ VERSION=v1 jade some.jade --out dist/$VERSION/` yep, you can use it with your command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell does not expand variables inside single quotes ('). You need to be inside double quotes ("). However, then the double quotes inside would need to be escaped. It looks messy but works:

```
jade some.jade -O "{\"version\": \"${VERSION}\"}"
```

Alternatively, you can juxtapose strings like this which also works:

```
jade some.jade -O '{"version": "'"${VERSION}"'"}'
```

Here there are 3 strings '...', "${VERSION}" and '"}'. Because there is no space between them, they count as one.